# Keep getting "Package hypcap Error: You have forgotten to use \caption." error from this part of my code

Tags: tables

I keep getting the error I listed above from this part of my code. When I take it out, it runs fine and I get no errors. This table is part of a chapter that gets input into a larger paper. This is plain TeX, a homemade document class that my professor made. Please help if you can.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{lllllllllllllllllllllllllll}
\textit{Plaintext Letter} & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & J & K  & L  & M  & N  & O  & P  & Q  & R  & S  & T  & U  & V  & W  & X  & Y  & Z \\\
\textit{Numerical Equivalent} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24  & 25 \\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please turn your code snippet into a minimal working example (MWE). This is a document that starts with `\documentclass`, includes the **relevant** packages, all the way to the final `\end{document}` command. This will allow us a complete overview to help you better with your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Package `hypcap` sets an anchor right at the beginning of the float via `\capstart` assuming the corresponding `\caption` command will follow, which is responsible for the number, which is used to derive an anchor name for `\capstart`. However, `\caption` is missing in the table float object of the question. Therefore the error message about a missing `\caption` is correct.

Since the anchor setting at the begin of the float is not needed here because of the missing `\caption`, the `\capstart` for this float can be disabled via `\capstartfalse` without loosing the automatically added `\capstart` for the other
float objects:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{table}
  \caption{First table}
\end{table}

\capstartfalse
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{lc*{25}{@{ }c}}
    \textit{Plaintext Letter} & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & J & K  & L
    & M  & N  & O  & P  & Q  & R  & S  & T  & U  & V  & W  & X  & Y  & Z \\
    \textit{Numerical Equivalent} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 &
    11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24  & 25
    \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\capstarttrue

\begin{table}
  \caption{Last table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```